# Center a DIV when animating

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I making a animation on set of **DIV's** which are wrapped inside `div` with `id="wrapper"`
using **CSS3**.
However if I hover on the **rounded box**, the animation  is **left aligned** but **not center** aligned.
The URL for the code is @http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ycu/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="roundedbox"></div>
<div class="ball"> </div>
<div class="greenball"> </div>
<div class="redball"> </div>
<div class="greenleaf"> </div>
<div id="pacman"> </div>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards

Alex

Comment: You could decrease the value of the "left" property during the animation. So you pretty much need to include new positions during the animation.

Answer (score 1):

change the blocks from inline-block to display: block
add margin 0 auto 
remove the position absolute

quick fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/X5Ycu/2/

```
#wrapper{
position:relative;
width: 400px
}

.roundedbox{
position:relative;
width:75px;
height: 75px;
background-color: pink;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px auto;
border-radius:10px;
transition-property:border-radius width;
transition-duration:2s;
transition-timing-function:linear;
```

}

Comment: Agreed. The problem is that there's nowhere else the rounded box can grow. By defining an absolute left position, you would be saying that left side of this box should always be at this pixel. Hence it grows to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
div.roundedbox:hover{
    width:100px;
    left: 137.5px; //Add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin applied effect like `TOP` and `BOTTOM` also `RIGHT` and `LEFT` to these two applied to half the original size

see that example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ycu/1/

```
.limeball{
   margin: 0px; // original margin
   width: 100px; //original width
   height: 50px; //original height
}

.limeball{
  width: 0px;
  height:0px;
  margin: 25px 50px;
  // margin  results:
  // (original width) / 2 = 50px (LEFT AND RIGHT)
  // (original height) / 2 = 25px (TOP AND BOTTOM)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use modern CSS as you say, then you could specify:

```
left: 50%; /* or figure out where the center is */
```

And then just move the element to its half size to the left, which you can do using `transform`:

```
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

So now, even when your element is changing its size, also its position (translation) will change according to its size. This (the translation) will always work, regardless of how your element is positioned or displayed.

You will surely need to use some vendor prefixes.